# How to correctly resize images to fit all screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, drawable

How can I physically (not programmatically) set image sizes for each of the following android screen sizes:

```
-ldpi
-mdpi
-hdpi
-xhdpi
-xxhdpi
```

I want to set them physically and just have the different drawable folders instead of changing the size of the bitmap, *unless* it is that much easier.

Comment: please google Android Asset Studio. it's a tool to resize image for you

Comment: Visit : http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/